# Vim keyboard shortcut general word count

Tags: vim

How do I count the words in a document in vim? According to vim's definition of a word.

Seems easy to answer however I couldn't find an answer on here as they all addressed word matches, or having it in a function. I just want the word count.

Answer (score 5):

The keyboard shortcut is g Ctrl-g.

**Thanks - Assaf Lavie**

For further information about the usage of this see `:help g`

**Thanks - Munen**

For those who have access to the GNU coreutils (E.G Linux) you can use the program wc see `man wc` for more information

```
:!wc -w %<tab>
```

The %tab expands to the current file in the buffer

Answer (score 5):

You may also find it useful to know that you could find the answer yourself using helpgrep.

e.g.

```
:helpgrep count words
```

You can then use `:cnext` to flip through the search result. Result #2 in this case is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I like using standard shell commands for such tasks. Therefore I would pipe the text to `wc`. Highlight the lines you want to count the words in, then:

```
:!wc -w
```

This will replace the text with the actual wordcount. Of course you can bring back your text by undoing the last action with `u`.

Comment: Maybe better, to avoid replacing the text: `:w !wc -w` (:help :w_c).